# Select a string which contain a sub-string within a defined boundaries using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following string (example)

```
"hhfghfgvcbfdsgvcfsdfgs{pattern}sdfdsfsdfdsfsdfdsfs"
```

I want to select the entire string (inside the "") if the pattern inside the string matches.

How can I do that using regular expression?

Thanks

Comment: Use `"[^"]*\{pattern\}[^"]*"`

Answer (score 0):

This patter should do what you want.

```
^".*?\{pattern}.*?"$
```

You can try it out on [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3ejk6).

In JavaScript:

```
text.match(/^".*?\{pattern}.*?"$/g);
```